# Dynamic action for route in Symfony 2.x (part of the url)

Tags: symfony, routes, action, dynamically-generated

Is it possible to define a route in Symfony 2.x that dynamically resolves the action based on part of the route ?

Example :

```
rest_localite:
    path:  /rest/localite/{_action}
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationLocaliteBundle:Rest:{_action}, _format: json }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was considered bad practice as it exposes internal parts of the application and last I heard they removed it.
If you are doing this to save time you might want to look at the `@Route` annotations for actions, it is less of a pain. 
But if you really cannot do without dynamic actions calls and do not mind the risk you could try passing the action's name as a parameter to a single controller method that then calls the appropriate method.